# Recommendation for dynamical system with complex behaviors

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I want to learn the behaviors of dynamical systems, especially the in form of $X'=f(X)$ and $X'=f(t,X)$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

I know Lorentz system is such a system(typically $\sigma=10,\beta=\frac{8}{3},\rho=28$).

\begin{array}{rcl}
\dot x &=& \sigma(y-x) \\
\dot y &=& \rho x-y-xz \\
\dot z &=& -\beta z+xy
\end{array}

Any other one which is famous or complex enough?

Comment: I think the Poincaré–Bendixson theorem implies that there are no such examples in dimension 2. But you may want to look at [limit cycles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_cycle) such as the one in the [Van der Pol oscillator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Pol_oscillator) for instance.

Comment: @lhf Thanks, but I'm more interested in $\mathbb{R}^3$ situation.

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/562928/practical-applications-of-chaos-theory-in-engineering-or-physics) are some other examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Lorenz system is famous for having a [strange attractor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attractor#Strange_attractor) despite being given by simple equations.

Other famous strange attractors also given by simple equations include the [Rössler attractor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%B6ssler_attractor) and [Chua's attractor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_scroll_attractor).

Comment: More example expected. Actually, these two systems can be found in wiki.